# Read only file-system error while downloading file from FTP in Android

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp, apache-commons

Im trying to download file from FTP in android using Apache Commons library and Im always getting Error EROFS (Read only file-system). I tried to make directory on the server instead, using ftpClient.makeDirectory("xxx") and that works completely fine. I also tried to do this without using    passive mode and I made sure that path to file is right but with the same result. Using total comander - everything works so its not the permission issue. Thanks for reply.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(xxx);
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("xxx",xxx);
ftpClient.login("xxx", "yyy");
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
FileOutputStream buffIn = null;
buffIn = new FileOutputStream(new File("/file")); //here I get the crash
ftpClient.retrieveFile("file", buffIn);

            buffIn.close();
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new File("/file")`. That is not possible as that would be in the root of the filesystem. So your path is wrong. You should first decide where to save the file. You can choose from internal, external or removable memory. Should it have the name 'file'?

Comment: Thanks. I thought that android automatically saves it where he is used to save downloads.